# Efficient way of sliding small array over larger to compare them

Tags: r

I have a set of black and white reference images stored and organized in a 3D array. in addition, I have a smaller "target" that is very similar to a piece of one of the other images. Imagine the reference images being satellite images of different cities, and my target image is a photo of an unknown city block in any of the cities. I want to identify where in which city the block is from.

I have simple code that works (simplified demo below), but with **three nested for loops** it's very slow.

Does anyone have a good idea of how to speed things up? Any thoughts appreciated!

**EDIT:** In the real scenario the images are already processed so that only important features remain, so that part works satisfactory. My main question is if the for loops can be substituted with something like the `apply()` function.

```
# create 100 artificial images (cities), stored in a 3D array. Each image is 100x100 "pixels"
reference_images = sample(c(0,1),1000000, replace = TRUE)
dim(reference_images) = c(100,100,100)

# create  target image (city block). This is the piece we want to find.
# NB! In this artificial case, we just copy a 50x50 piece from the 7th of the randomly generated 
# reference images. This is obviously only useful for this demo, in the real case the  
# target image comes from an other source.
target_image = reference_images[51:100,51:100,7]

# example image
library(grid)
grid.raster(reference_images[,,1],interpolate = F)
# target_image
grid.raster(target_image,interpolate = F)

# array to store the error of each match. 
# The 50x50 target image can be compared to 51*51 positions in each of the 100x100 images.
# The error array will therefor be 51x51x100, each position corresponding to the position 
# of the "top left corner" of the target image when compared to the candidate images. 
error = rep(NA,51*51*100)
dim(error) = c(51,51,100)

# (SLOW!)
# Loop through each comparable position of each candidate image and stor the error of each
# By image...
for(k in 1:dim(reference_images)[3]){
  # by row...
  for(i in 1:51){
    # by column...
    for(j in 1:51){
      error[i,j,k] = sum(target_image != reference_images[i:(i+49),j:(j+49), k])
    }
  }
}

# If everything went as expected, the error of position [51,51,7] should be 0.
error[,,7]
```

Comment: How big are your query and target datasets?

Comment: My query ('target_image' above) is about 50x50 pixels, I need to search through about 40 reference images, each about 350x250 pixels.

That may only take a few minutes, but this is all part of a Shiny app that needs to be pretty quick not to be frustrating.

Comment: Sorry, living in a different world. I was imagining something like thousands of references, and even more queries. Here you just need to optimize the inner two loops. I will try something.

Comment: @liborm Awesome, thanks. Yes, the problem has been reduced in several ways in previous steps. I actually start with about 2300 reference images and that are each 1040x1392 pixels, and a query image that is about the same size. But down sampling and exclusion of reference images only get me this far. Would love to replace the for loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, which is not perfect, but shows the direction. For mentioned size of data set it should be enough to move the two inner loops from R to some compiled extension. `raster`'s focal is a candidate:

```
library(raster)
target_image <- reference_images[50:100,50:100,7]

best_match <- function(i) max(as.matrix(focal(raster(i), target_image, pad = T, padValue = 0)))
apply(reference_images, 3, best_match)
```

Identifies image #7 as best candidate in ~8 seconds (Intel i7 CPU):

```
[1]  714  710  718  716  720  710 1327  724  727  717  703  720  718  715  712  722  715  711  711  722  702  747  705
[24]  717  725  744  744  713  736  726  724  706  725  716  710  728  715  709  695  719  717  736  733  702  695  718
[47]  711  714  712  713  733  692  714  702  719  717  717  719  703  701  718  726  704  713  712  725  712  708  721
[70]  706  709  715  707  718  723  714  708  703  712  737  720  701  737  723  723  720  732  714  703  708  719  727
[93]  703  723  705  711  702  699  712  700
```

It is a bit hacky - `focal` needs odd sized windows (query) and calculates a convolution of the query and the target (sum of element-wise products), but for a binary image this works well, giving a high score for exact match.

Some more generic suggestions (thinking of a dataset of thousands images, even more queries):

Given the data are images, I would try matching with some [image feature descriptors](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html#py-table-of-content-feature2d). 'Landmarks' in the image are converted to 30-60 dimensional vectors, indexed into something like a KD-tree, and efficiently searched and matched.

Another approach to image patch matching I've seen is [cross correlation through FFT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18401-efficient-subpixel-image-registration-by-cross-correlation/content/html/efficient_subpixel_registration.html). The link is on matlab, but still could serve as a guidance.

EDIT: sorry for generic suggestions, I was just trying to hint the OP in a good direction.

Comment: Great solution, works very well here and is faster than I'd ever hoped for! I think I'll be able to work this into my program, will see how it performs on the real data where the match isn't as exact. Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the hack, maybe you'll be able to find some other extension that does subtraction of the window instead of convolution, which would be more appropriate. If you're doing more image processing / computer vision, you should maybe look into [scikit image](http://scikit-image.org/) or the aforementioned OpenCV, both can be controlled with Python. R is not very friendly for this kind of tasks (yet?;).